# HTML/CSS "Responsive Truncation"

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I recently launched a responsive version of my site, however I'm finding that percentage width divisions containing a number of single lines of text look really bad, as fitting everything on a single line in both the desktop and mobile views results in each single line of text being either too long or too short.

My markup is a single unordered list of links (with long anchor texts) - does anyone have any suggestions to truncate the anchor text according to the width of the containing division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with two options:

One is to do it yourself using javascript as described here:

[Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

I don't think there is any way to determine the width of the text until the browser actually renders the text.

Make sure you don't display: none it, or the browser won't actually render it and you can't determine the width.

The second is to let CSS do it for you; it's easier, but you lose pretty much all flexibility:

If you're willing to let CSS guess at how to cut off your text into ellipsis, you can try text-overflow: ellipsis

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html